# Identifying a function that involves combinations of terms

Tags: combinatorics, functions, soft-question, special-functions

I need to know if a function exists that partitions terms in such a way as seen below

$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[\frac{(x)_c}{n!}]
$$
Note that $(x)_c$ is the falling factorial of x and $c \geq n$, This in turn partitions the terms within the falling factorial. Here is an example:

$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[\frac{(x)_4}{2!}] = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}[\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{2}]$$

$$ =\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx}[ x(x-1)(x-2)+x(x-2)(x-3)+x(x-1)(x-3)+(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)]$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} [2x(x-1)+2x(x-2)+2x(x-3)+2(x-1)(x-2)+2(x-2)(x-3)+2(x-1)(x-3)]$$

$$ = x(x-1)+x(x-2)+x(x-3)+(x-1)(x-2)+(x-1)(x-2)+(x-2)(x-3)$$

This seems similar to bell polynomials or something of the sort, I don't know if such a function even exists. All help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: The questioner has opened a new question in which he proposes a (correct) answer to this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028232/a-question-about-the-elementary-symmetric-polynomial/